# how to switch language from an array with react hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

i want to change the language of a quote, from French to English or inverse when i click on "lang button", the quote is generate randomly from an array when the page start.
this is my array:

```
const quoteData = [
  {
    quoteEn:
      "Three things cannot be long hidden: the sun, the moon, and the truth.",
    quoteFr:
      "Trois choses ne peuvent pas être cachées longtemps : le soleil, la lune et la vérité.",
    author: "Buddha"
  },
  {
    quoteEn:
      "We make a living by what we get, but we make a life by what we give.",
    quoteFr:
      "On vit de ce que l’on obtient. On construit sa vie sur ce que l’on donne.",
    author: "Winston Churchill"
  }

export default quoteData;
```

and this is what i tried:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import quoteData from "./components/quoteData";
import "./App.css";
import { ReactComponent as Github } from "./icons/github-brands.svg";

function App() {
  const getRandomQuotes = () => {
    const randNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteData.length);
    return quoteData[randNumb];
  };

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(getRandomQuotes());
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState(getRandomQuotes().author);
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("En");
  const [nextBtn, setNextBtn] = useState("Next");

  const handleClickLang = () => {
    if (lang === "Fr") {
      setLang("En");
      setNextBtn("Next");
      setQuote(quote.quoteFr);
    } else {
      setLang("Fr");
      setNextBtn("Suivant");
      setQuote(quote.quoteEn);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div className="c1">
        <div className="lang">
          <button onClick={handleClickLang} className="changeLang">
            {lang}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="card flow">
          <p id="text">{quote}</p>
          <p id="author">{author}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="c2">
        <Github id="github" />
        <button onClick={handleClickRandomQuote} id="new-quote">
          {nextBtn}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

and i get this error : Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {quoteEn, quoteFr, author}).

Comment: `<p id="text">{quote}</p>` is your problem - `quote` is an object, not a string or an array of React element instances.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are storing in your `quote` state an object (the one you randomly select from your array of `quoteData`), not the string for the quote. This is not bad, as you also want to show the author of the random quote you randomly selected.

Also, when you do:

```
const [quote, setQuote] = useState(getRandomQuotes());
const [author, setAuthor] = useState(getRandomQuotes().author);
```

You have to take into account that the first execution of `getRandomQuotes` will return a random quote that doesn't have to coincide with the second call to `getRandomQuotes` to get the author. This could cause that your data (quote and author) are not in sync.

So, it seems that storing the author separately from the quote is not necessary. Taking all this into account, you could do something like:

```
function App() {
  const getRandomQuotes = () => {
    const randNumb = Math.floor(Math.random() * quoteData.length);
    return quoteData[randNumb];
  };

  const [quote, setQuote] = useState(getRandomQuotes());
  const [lang, setLang] = useState("En");
  const [nextBtn, setNextBtn] = useState("Next");

  const handleClickLang = () => {
    if (lang === "Fr") {
      setLang("En");
      setNextBtn("Next");
    } else {
      setLang("Fr");
      setNextBtn("Suivant");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div id="quote-box">
      <div className="c1">
        <div className="lang">
          <button onClick={handleClickLang} className="changeLang">
            {lang}
          </button>
        </div>
        <div className="card flow">
          <p id="text">{quote[`quote${lang}`]}</p>
          <p id="author">{quote.author}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="c2">
        <Github id="github" />
        <button onClick={handleClickRandomQuote} id="new-quote">
          {nextBtn}
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```